# Why is there an OS segment reserved in virtual memory

Tags: operating-system, segmentation-fault, virtual-memory

1. Why is there a portion of virtual memory reserved for OS? Why is it limited to a certain size? This seems to be a universally known fact because when I googled I didn't find anyone asking similar questions.
2. If the OS segment (the part in VM reserved for OS) is accessed, what happens?
3. How does the OS segment affect the translation between virtual and physical memory?
4. For example if your virtual memory is 128KB, the first 32KB is allocated for seg 0 and the last 32KB for seg 1. Then you reserve the first 16KB for the OS seg. What happens to seg 0? Does its size shrink to 16KB because 16KB has been changed to OS seg? Or does it stays the same?

Comment: What if there wasn't and you ran out of VM. 
 the kernel is only so big.

Comment: what does `OS segment` mean?

Comment: @Jasen Sorry, I was referring to the part in VM reserved for OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there a portion of virtual memory reserved for OS? Why is it limited to a certain size? This seems to be a universally known fact because when I googled I didn't find anyone asking similar questions.

The reason some area of the logical address space is reserved for the OS is because the same physical memory is shared by all processes and it needs to be at the same location.

When an interrupt occurs, any process can be running. So the kernel mode handler needs to be in the same location.

Usually the reserved OS area is so large that the actual OS will never come close to using it all. So it is not really limited in size.

> If the OS segment is accessed, what happens?

That depends upon how it is accessed. If a process accesses it in kernel mode (system call, interrupt, exception), that is normal. If it accesses the reserved area in user mode, it usually triggers an access violation of some kind. Some systems may make some areas of system memory readable from user mode but usually is all write protected.

> How does the OS segment affect the translation between virtual and physical memory?

This is system dependent. Some systems make the user page tables pageable. The user page tables can then be in pageable areas in the system address space. In other words, the page tables are in virtual/logical memory, giving an additional translation for user addresses that does not occur for system addresses

Doing the same for the system address space would cause a chicken and egg problem. In such a system, the system page tables would be in physical locations (another reason everyone uses the same address range for system space).

Other systems use physical addresses for all page tables. In case, they translation is the same.

> For example if your virtual memory is 128KB, the first 32KB is allocated for seg 0 and the last 32KB for seg 1. Then you reserve the first 16KB for the OS seg. What happens to seg 0? Does its size shrink to 16KB because 16KB has been changed to OS seg? Or does it stays the same?

This is not a good example. Virtual memory is never this small. Imagine a 32-bit system. The virtual address space is 4GB. The system assigns the first 3 GB to user the user space and the last 1 GB to the system space.

All processes share the same 1GB system space. They have there own, unique 3 GB user space.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very detailed explanation.